# User login not working after password update

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to make a forgot password feature in my Symfony 3.1 application.

I have a form sending an email with an url to reset the password, with a security token.
You then land on a simple form containing a password input.

On submit, I update the user password with the one they submitted, but then when I try to login, it says the credentials are wrong.

I can see that the password is beeing updated in the database, but I don't get why it's not working when I try to login.

Here is the code that updates the password :

```
// retrieve the user
 $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->findOneBy(array('username' => "admin", "token" => $token));

//the password posted from the form
$password = $request->get('new_password');

$em      = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

//encoding it according to the symfony doc
//see https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/security/password_encoding.html
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $password);

//updating the password in the database
$user->setPassword($encoded);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

I have an encoder set in my security.yaml file :

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
```

Firewall in the security.yaml :

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/connexion
            check_path: /admin/connexion
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

Password property in User.php class :

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $password;
```

Password field in config/doctrine/User.orm.xml :

```
<field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="64"/>
```

Comment: What kind of firewall do you use for the login(a custom?) ?
Is the value of $password correct (same as the one entered in your form) ?
What are the annotations of the password property of your entity?

To verify that your password is not changed in the meantime: If you do not enter your password, is the value in the database the same as your password in clear?

Comment: I added the firewalls part of my security.yaml
The $password is correct (contains the password I entered in the form)
No particular annotation for the password property (see the added code)
I don't understand your last question, you mean if I submit an empty password ? In this case the password is still updated (looks like this : $2y$13$.zevhbcGaF8OS.ZhpOJKiuktuOsl5aYgorOiO3M3q7Kqe30m0/N.e)

Comment: Sorry, I'm rephrasing: If you modify your password without encoding it, is its value in mysql the same as in the form?

Comment: No problem, yes I just tested without encoding the password, and it was saved in plain text in the database

Comment: Try to debug at vendor/symfony/security-core/Encoder/UserPasswordEncoder.php:46 when you are trying to login :
- $raw should be your password in clear
- $user->getPassword() should be your hashed password
- $encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $raw, $user->getSalt()); should be true

Comment: Ok I feel really dumb now, the issue was something else : I had two providers, one for users coming from the database, and one for a hardcoded user in_memory, and I forgot to create a chain provider as explained here : https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/security/multiple_user_providers.html
I'm sorry for that.. But thanks a lot for your (wasted) time Alex !

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from my providers : I had two providers, one for users coming from the database, and one for a hardcoded user in_memory, and I forgot to create a chain provider as explained here : [symfony.com/doc/3.1/security/multiple_user_providers.html](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/security/multiple_user_providers.html)